# Mapstruct how to initialize fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a DTO like this

```
@Data
public class MessageDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
}
```

and an entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Instant timestamp;
}
```

I want to create a mapper to map DTO to entity. How can I make the field `private Instant timestamp;` has value like Instant.now()?

My mapper so far

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", imports = Instant.class)
public interface MessageMapper extends EntityMapper<MessageDTO, Message> {
    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "timestamp", source = "" ,defaultExpression = "java(Instant.now())")
    Message toEntity(MessageDTO dto);
}
```

It got compile error

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/Shared/projects/IdeaProjects/medical/src/main/java/io/medical/service/mapper/MessageMapper.java:[22,45] No property named "" exists in source parameter(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the `source` being empty. Remove the `source` and use `expression` instead of `defaultExpression`.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MessageMapper extends EntityMapper<MessageDTO, Message> {
    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "timestamp", expression = "java(Instant.now())")
    Message toEntity(MessageDTO dto);
}
```

When there is a source but the source is null upon resolving, then `defaultExpression` comes handy to assign a value to the target.